# Calling an overridden superclass method from a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
public class F {
    protected int a=0, b=0;
   public F() {
     a = 2;
     b = 2;
     }
  public void increase() {
     upA();
  } 
  public void upA() {
     a = a + 1;
  }
  public String toString() {
     return a+" "+b;
   }
 }
```

---

```
 public class G extends F {
      public void increase() {
            super.increase();
            upB();
      }
     public void upA() {
            a = a + a;
     }
     public void upB() {
          b = b + 1;
   }
 }
```

What is printed in the Output window by the following Java fragment?

```
 G g = new G();
 g.increase();
 System.out.println(g);
```

Can someone explain to me why the answer is `4,3`

(ie. the subclass method is called even though I have called super.increase() which calls the upA method in the superclass?)

Comment: Please format your code - it's *horrible* to read at the moment, and clarify your question - *which* subclass method is called unexpectedly?

Comment: I suggest you to Use Debugger for better understanding!!

Answer (score 6):

All your methods are being called virtually, with overrides applying. So this code in `F`:

```
public void increase() {
    upA();
}
```

... is invoking `G.upA()`, because the object it's calling `upA()` on is an instance of `G`.

So the execution flow for `increase()` is:

- `G.increase()` calls `super.increase()`

  - `F.increase()` calls `upA()`
  - `G.upA()` executes (so a = 4)
- `G.increase()` calls `upB()`

  - `G.upB()` executes (so b = 3)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: well explained @Jon Skeet. I was just wondering is it possible to strict any how so that the `super.increase()` will invoke the parent method `F.upA()` ?

Comment: @Saif: No, there's no way of calling it "non-virtually".

Answer (score 2):

Think of increase() as being implemented like this

```
public void increase() {
  this.upA();
}
```

and then ask yourself what object "this" is.

You are seeing "polymorphic" behaviour, and it's a really powerful feature of Object languages.

Note that you can write

```
  F gInDisguiseAsAnF = new G();

  gInDisguiseAsAnF.increase();
```

and still get the same result. Which version of the upA() method is selected on the basis of the type that was newed.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void increase() {
  upA();
  }
```

is same as `this.upA()`, so the method in `G` was called, since `this` is instance of `G`.

calling super won't restrict your current instance only in super type.

Comment: Ahh I never thought of it like that, that makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

This is being called from increase() of F

```
public void upA() {
 a = a + a; // a=2+2 
  }
```

Not,

```
  public void upA() {
  a = a + 1; //not a=2+1
  }
```